# How to save View's state after pause?

Tags: android, android-savedstate, mosby

When my app completes some async tasks, it notifies UI about it.

For example:

1. user clicks on "Do work" button inside of my application `-> async work started`
2. and switches to another app `-> state is saved`
3. then "work" inside my app is finished and View-s updated  `-> async work finished` *(note that my activity is paused)*
4. User rotates the phone and then navigating back to my app
5. **problem:** `state is restored` and View's state updated in 3 step is gone while work was finished!

How to deal with such cases?
Is there any way to save settings after app is paused?

Comment: How about caching (keeping that value in RAM)?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [MvpQueuingBasePresenter](https://github.com/sockeqwe/mosby/blob/master/mvp-queuing-presenter/src/main/java/com/hannesdorfmann/mosby3/mvp/MvpQueuingBasePresenter.java) or Model-View-Intent which deals better with lifecycle related things.

Comment: `MvpQueuingBasePresenter` won't help as it is still attached while Activity(and fragments) are paused. View(and Android-Views) still can be changed while activity is paused and after orientation changes when the user resume activity it will lose state modifications made after an app was paused. Can I have Presenter be attached only between `RESUME` and `PAUSE` with Mosby 3 MVP?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should update the state of the view in onResume method from that activity.

ref: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html